# Generate classes from xsd in Java ( Jaxb )

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I need some help please ! I'm trying to generate classes from xsd in java ( with eclipse ) and I don't know how to do it, I searched in many tutorials but they all speaks about creating firstly the class then using the xsd.
I want to create automatically the classes from a xsd using Jaxb.
do you have any suggestions or tutorials that can help me please ?

Comment: You could look into using a tool called XMLBeans.  It is a bit old and deprecated but for a student project it should be just fine (actually we use it in production, but don't tell anybody that).

Comment: thank you for your reply but  it's not  a student project it's for my work , I have to create an applicaiton that reads the input XML files , and stock their content in a database, (that's why i need to use jaxb to creates classes from the Xml )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it ! 
I will show my solution, in case someone have the same problem.
i used ProcessBuilder in a method in order to execute the command from java :

public class FromXmlToJava implements Runnable {

private final InputStream inputStream;

```
 FromXmlToJava ( InputStream inputStream)
    {

     this.inputStream = inputStream;

    }

 private BufferedReader getBufferedReader(InputStream is) 
    {
      return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    }

public void run() {

    BufferedReader br = getBufferedReader(inputStream);
    String ligne = "";
    try 
    {
        while ( (ligne = br.readLine() )!= null)
        {


            System.out.println(ligne);
        }


    } catch (IOException e) 

        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


}

public static class Main {
    // chemin de l'emplacement des classes generées 

    public static final String CHEMIN = "C:\\Users\\****";
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C",
                        "C:\\Users\\***\\xjc.bat ***.xsd");

                // modifier le repertoire d'execution de la commande 

                pb.directory(new File(CHEMIN));



               /* Map env = pb.environment();
                for (Entry entry : env.entrySet()) {
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
                }

                env.put("MonArg", "Valeur");
                */
                Process p = pb.start();
                FromXmlToJava fluxSortie = new FromXmlToJava(p.getInputStream());
                FromXmlToJava fluxErreur = new FromXmlToJava(p.getErrorStream());
                new Thread(fluxSortie).start();
                new Thread(fluxErreur).start();
                p.waitFor();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`xjc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/xjc.html) command that comes with the JDK:

> Compiles an XML schema file into fully annotated Java classes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply , can i create an application that do it automatically ? do you know any tutorial that can help me ? please

Comment: You can run the `xjc` executable, or you can call it directly by adding `tools.jar` (from JDK `lib` folder) to your classpath, then invoke `com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Driver.main(String[] args)`.